# INDIRECT FORMULA

Tags: excel, formula, sumproduct

I am having trouble working out an error I am having with the formula below, I am a bit of a novice and its been more trial and error than anything so far but, I was hoping someone with a far greater knowledge could point out where I am going wrong.

The formula works fine without the indirect element I.e.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((PARROT!$o$12:$o$250<>"COMPLETE")*(PARROT!$n$12:$n$250<TODAY()))
```

but I want to replace the sheet name with an INDIRECT address as the name of the sheet could change

so the formula I came up with is but, it has an error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!$o$12:$o$250"),"<>"&"Complete")*(INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!$N$12:$N$250")<TODAY())
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your formula it seems you are just counting rows where `O12:O250` is not equal `Complete` and `N12:N250` is earlier than today. So, you can use `COUNTIFS()` formula with `INDIRECT()` easily. Try below.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($A$3&"!$O$12:$O$250"),"<>Complete",INDIRECT($A$3&"!$N$12:$N$250"),"<"&TODAY())
```

If you need to sum values from a column then `SUMIFS()` will be your friend.